# Can't figure out what these arrows in my C code are

Tags: c

I was given this code to look into, and this code is filled with these arrow type symbols:

[image: snapshot]

Those symbols are seen around variable declarations like in the image, and they disappear if I copy them and try to paste them into web browser. Are they like some sort of custom symbol from different keyboard? What could possibly be their functions? I checked preprocessor macros, and it does not have any macro defined for arrow symbols.

Comment: Do not post pictures, do not post whole code, make a [mcve]. It cannot be long for showing the symbols you refer to.

Comment: What are you using to view this code?

Comment: They're tab characters.  In whatever editor you're using, there's a setting to show tab characters turned on.

Comment: The arrows are representations of white space (in this case probably tabulators). The compiler ignores them. (By the way, I admit that in this rare case, posting a picture was the right way.)

Comment: @chris R. timmons hmm, i think that might be it. This didn't occur to be because when i type code myself the white spaces do not show up as arrows. I am using codeblocks, ill try and check settings. Thank you.

Comment: By the way this code may have a security vulnerability in case the string is longer than `INT_MAX`

Comment: @HarryLincolnKomol IMO it is better to disable (substitute) the 'TAB' character in the source code editor. That will make cursor movement and deleting text more predictable, generally easier to manage.

Comment: Notice that a small middle dot is displayed there instead of the space character too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those arrow symbols are actually visualizations of the tab character.  What you actually have is this:

```
void    *ptr;
int     len = strlen( string ) + 1;
```

The arrows are there just to show you that there are tabs in the code.

Comment: huh i see, thank you. This did not occur to me because when i type code in the editor myself the tabs do not appear as arrows. Ill try checking  my ide settings.